# two combobox firing an event for same function

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindexchanged

There are two comboboxes. one is created by drag&drop and set event SelectedIndexChanged. And 2nd combobox is created manually, but not given any event. But when I change 2nd combo, it's firing an event for 1st combo's function.

```
Form prompt = new Form();
prompt.Width = 300;
prompt.Height = 150;

    ComboBox cmBox = new ComboBox() { Left = 70, Top = 24, Width = 100, Height=150 };
    cmBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    cmBox.ValueMember = "value";
    cmBox.DisplayMember = "text";

prompt.ShowDialog();
```

I tried, but not working:

```
cmBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

P.S: They are using same bindsource.

Comment: Did you actually add cmBox to the form?  You only posted *some* of the code.

Comment: If you have the same binding source (which you haven't documented) then they both would be using the same currency manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're sharing a `BindingSource`, then changing the value in one control will change the value in the other control as well.

When you change the value in the second `ComboBox`, the value in the first `ComboBox` changes too, which fires its `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Create a separate `BindingSource` for each control, or if it's a collection, try just assigning the collection directly to each `ComboBox`.

Comment: I've created new binding source and the problem is solved.thanks.